# Optimizing collection filtering

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models: Account - Partner - User, with the 3 in belongsToMany relations (account_user, account_partner). I would like to filter all the User partners, authorized by the User accounts.

I have wrote the basic foreach loop hell, and I would like to ask for some tips for optimizing this filtering (like evading n+1 and other problems).

```
$userPartners = [];

foreach (auth()->user()->accounts as $account) {
    foreach ($account->partners as $partner) {
        $inList = false;

        foreach ($userPartners as $userPartner) {
            if ($userPartner->id === $partner->id) {
               $inList = true;
            }
        }

        if (!$inList) {
           $userPartners[] = $partner;
        }
    }
}
dd($userPartners);
```

Comment: please indent code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**Controller.php**

```
$userPartners = collect();
auth()->user()->accounts->each(function($account) use ($userPartners) {
    $account->partners->each(function($partner) use ($userPartners) {
        if(!$userPartners->contains('id', $partner->id)) $userPartners->push($partner);
    });
});
dd($userPartners);
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by eager loading your relationships with `load`. This will avoid the `N+1` problem:

```
$user = auth()->user()->load('accounts');
$userPartners = [];

$user->accounts->each(function ($account) use ($userPartners) {
    $ids =  $account->partners->pluck('id');
    if (!in_array($account->id, $ids)) {
        $userPartners[] = $account->partners->where('id', $account->id);
    }
});
```

Comment: ```auth()->user``` doesn't exist. ```user()``` is a method for the ```auth()``` helper.